# playlist de musica com opção de play, e download

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, css3

Gostaria de saber como faço uma playlist de música dese tipo .
com as músicas uma abaixo da outra, a opção de dar play para ouvir, e outra opção de baixar uma por uma. Que no caso ficara no lugar da bolinha azul e vermelha[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: E em qual parte exatamente está com dificuldade? Em estruturar o HTML? Em aplicar o estilo com CSS? Em executar uma música com JS? Em baixar um arquivo?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss em executar a musica com javascript

Comment: Então elabore um [mcve] já adicionando o HTML, CSS, JS que possui reproduzindo a tela que possui.